# How do I reduce alert-dialogue code from main-activity in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a class where I am writing three different alert dialogue. These three alert dialogue extends the line of code of this class drastically. So for re-factoring purpose, I want to make base class for three alert dialogue and use this class in the main activity. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this? My three alert dialogue are given below:

```
public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message,
                final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity)
                    .setTitle("Confirmation")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    result.confirm();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    result.cancel();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();

            return true;
        }



        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity)
                    .setTitle("Alert !")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    result.confirm();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();

            return true;
        } 


    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

            final boolean remember = true;

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    WebviewActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Locations");
            builder.setMessage(" Would like to use your Current Location")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Allow",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);

                                    SharedPreferences pref = currentActivity
                                            .getPreferences(currentActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref
                                            .edit();
                                    editor.putBoolean("isLocationAvailable",
                                            true);
                                    editor.commit();

                                    webview.loadUrl(getUrl(gps.getLatitude(),
                                            gps.getLongitude(), "true"));
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Don't Allow",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                                    webview.loadUrl(getUrl("", "", "false"));

                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

Comment: make a common function for alert ,pass parameters message , title and context to that function and your code will be reduced.

Comment: Did you check the code? Each alert dialogue works differently, so if I want to write function I have to write different function for each alert dialogue. So it will not reduce the code at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Complete solution Try this is a Generic Alert dialog with cutom tilte,message,yes,no button caption**

**1) Createa Interface**

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public interface AlertMagnatic {

    public abstract void PositiveMethod(DialogInterface dialog, int id);
    public abstract void NegativeMethod(DialogInterface dialog, int id);
}
```

**2) Generalize method for confirm dialog.**

```
public static void getConfirmDialog(Context mContext,String title, String msg, String positiveBtnCaption, String negativeBtnCaption, boolean isCancelable, final AlertMagnatic target) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        int imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        Drawable image = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

        builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(msg).setIcon(image).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(positiveBtnCaption, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                target.PositiveMethod(dialog, id);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(negativeBtnCaption, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                target.NegativeMethod(dialog, id);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setCancelable(isCancelable);
        alert.show();
        if (isCancelable) {
            alert.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    target.NegativeMethod(null, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**3) How to use**

```
getConfirmDialog(getString(R.string.logout), getString(R.string.logout_message), getString(R.string.yes), getString(R.string.no), false,
                new AlertMagnatic() {

                    @Override
                    public void PositiveMethod(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {}

                    @Override
                    public void NegativeMethod(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: this answer also demonstrates the same what i have mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: dialog does not survive screen rotation.